# Multithreading in the program does not work for me, what could be the problem?

Tags: python, multithreading, parsing, asynchronous, request

I'm trying to make my account autoregister on 1 of the servicers using python. I decided to resort to multithreading. I enter the number of threads I need into the console, but they do not start asynchronously. At first, the first thread finishes its work, then the 2nd one starts, and so on. As a result, such a program works very slowly, how can this be fixed?

<--- starting multithreading (Here I split the base of logins into the number of threads, maximum 100/10 = 10 logins per thread and transfer them to the thread itself) --->

```py
    for v in range(int(thread_count)):
        if(lines[v]):
            worker = Thread(target=sendRequest(v, lines[v], proxies, proxy_type))
            threads.append(worker)

    for x in threads:
        x.start()
```

<--- For each line passed to the stream, I create an asynchronous request --->

```py
def sendRequest(th_count, names, proxy, proxy_type):
    for x in names:
            loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
            asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
            res = loop.run_until_complete(register(x, proxy, proxy_type, th_count))
            loop.close()
```

<--- Here is the function of sending a get request. --->

```py
async def checking(name, proxy_array, proxy_type, th):
    random_proxy = proxy_array[random.randint(0, len(proxy_array) - 1)].rstrip()
    if proxy_type == 0:
        prox = f'socks4://{random_proxy}'
        proxies = {
            'http': prox,
            'https': prox
        }
    elif proxy_type == 1:
        prox = f'socks5://{random_proxy}'
        proxies = {
            'http': prox,
            'https': prox
        }
    try:
        r = requests.get("https://www.google.com/", proxies=proxies, timeout=3)
        print(f'{th} - {r}')
    except:
        print('err')
```

I've tried everything, but it still works terribly long, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. But the threads do not want to run all at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have in part:

```py
            ...
            worker = Thread(target=sendRequest(v, lines[v], proxies, proxy_type))
            ...
```

The first argument to the `Thread` initializer should be a reference to the "worker" function, `sendRequest` in this case, that you want multithreaded and the remaining arguments will be actual arguments passed to your worker function after the thread has been started. The *args* keyword argument is used to pass an *iterable* of all the positional arguments you want to pass to your worker function and the *kwargs* keyword arguments is used to pass a dictionary of keyword argument names and values that will be the keyword arguments passed to your worker function.

What you are doing is passing only a single argument to the `Thread` initializer that is the return value form calling `sendRequest(v, lines[v], proxies, proxy_type)` *in the current thread*. This return value appears to be `None` looking at the function definition for `sendRequest` and that is not a legal function reference. So all your `start` requests will fail. **So instead of passing a function reference you are actually calling the function and passing its return value.**

**TL;DR**

What you need is:

```py
            worker = Thread(target=sendRequest, args=(v, lines[v], proxies, proxy_type))
```